# WebScraping using PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, web-services, selenium-webdriver, flask

```
def Websiteopener():
    global driver
    url = "https://flowgpt.com/chat"
    chrome_option = Options()
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2"
    chrome_option.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")
    chrome_option.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
    chrome_option.add_argument("--headless=new")
    chrome_option.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={ScriptDir}\\chromedata')
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_option)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url=url)

    while True:
        try:
            xPATH = '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/textarea'
            driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xPATH)
            Checker()
            break
        except:
            sleep(5)
            pass
```

---

I have this Websiteopener Function which I am calling from my main file.
I have uploaded this file on pythonanywhere and it is giving me error everytime I am calling it.

---

```
2024-01-10 19:39:36,098: ====== WebDriver manager ======
2024-01-10 19:39:36,116: Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-01-10 19:39:36,116: Exception on /get_flow_reply [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/us2002/assistant/main.py", line 62, in get_flow_reply
    Websiteopener()
  File "/home/us2002/assistant/flowgpt.py", line 45, in Websiteopener
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  File "/home/us2002/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py", line 40, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
  File "/home/us2002/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/manager.py", line 40, in _get_driver_binary_path
    file = self._download_manager.download_file(driver.get_driver_download_url(os_type))
  File "/home/us2002/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py", line 32, in get_driver_download_url
    driver_version_to_download = self.get_driver_version_to_download()
  File "/home/us2002/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver.py", line 48, in get_driver_version_to_download
    return self.get_latest_release_version()
  File "/home/us2002/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py", line 64, in get_latest_release_version
    determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I have updated selenium to latest version but still getting this error
I want to open the website and work properly

When I am running it in local it is working fine but while running in pythonanywhere it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `add_argument("--no-sandbox")`. See example in https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium

Comment: It didn't helped, I got a reply from pythonanywhere they told me I cannot use webdrivermanager on pythonanywhere.